# PHPUnit test shows error with Global while running test in --order-by=reverse

Tags: php, phpunit

We are trying to fix our existing test case while running in reverse order. We recently updated our PHPUnit to PHPUnit 7.3 (Ref: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/ChangeLog-7.3.md)

**Error:**

> Undefined index: log

When I run the test in `--order-by=reverse` the following line shows error.

```
 $GLOBALS['log']->error(__METHOD__ . ": Not found");
```

I tried to fix this by adding **setUp()** function with the following:

```
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $GLOBALS['log'] = '';
    }

Error: Call to a member function error() on string
```

I am not sure how to write this error since each function will have different error log messages.

Similar functions:

```
$GLOBALS['log']->debug(__METHOD__ . $message);
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to this

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $GLOBALS['log'] = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('LoggerTemplate')
        ->setMethods(array('log', 'debug'))
        ->getMock();
}

protected function tearDown()
{
    unset($GLOBALS['log']);
}
```

Hope this helps someone!!!!